# How does HAProxy figure out SSL_FC_SNI for map_dom

Tags: ssl, haproxy

I have a haproxy config using maps.

HAProxy config file has the below line:

```
%[ssl_fc_sni,lower,map_dom(/etc/haproxy/domain2backend.map)]
```

And in the domain2backend.map, i have the below entries:

```
dp.stg.corp.mydom.com dp_10293
/dp dp_10293
dp.admin.stg.corp.mydom.com dp_10345
```

Now when i access `https://dp.admin.stg.corp.mydom.com/index.html` it is directing me to backend `dp_10293` .  However using a simple full string match of map(/etc/haproxy/domain2backend.map) solves the problem and it directs me to proper backend `dp_10345`. The certs which i have is wildcard cert *.mydom.com

So how is map_dom comparing the domains and how is it directing request meant for `dp.admin.stg.corp.mydom.com` to backend of `dp.stg.corp.mydom.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i am using `map_dom`, it splits up the domain based on dots(.) and does a token matching and which ever is the first match, it returns that backend.

Here dp.admin.stg.corp.mydom.com matches any of

```
dp.admin.stg.corp.mydom.com
/dp
/admin
/stg
/corp
/mydom
/com
/dp.admin
/dp.admin.stg
/dp.admin.stg.corp
/dp.admin.stg.corp.mydom
/admin.stg.corp.mydom.com
/stg.corp.mydom.com
/corp.mydom.com
/mydom.com
```

And in my case, since i had a entry for /dp, it was routing to backend `dp_10345`.

Changing `map_dom` to `map` will fix it as map does a strict string comparison.